# Modern Mac mini does not autoboot after "dirty" shutdown from command line

Tags: command-line, mac, shutdown

Cross-posted to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374390/mac-mini-not-autobooting-after-dirty-shutdown)

This 2018 Mac mini running Mojave is intended to run as a kiosk, but a daily sleep/wake cycle is proving problematic with some USB devices.

My plan was to use the "dirty" shutdown from the command line to simulate a UPS shutdown: `sudo shutdown -hu now`.

- Enabled "Start automatically after a power failure" option in Energy Saver prefs
- execute the dirty shutdown from the command line
- remove power once the power light goes out, but before the 5 minute timeout.
- wait > 10 mins
- reapply mains power

expected result: Mac starts up.
actual result: Mac remains in powered-off state.

Please note I do NOT have a UPS connected to the system. `pmset -u...` commands are completely ignored.

Tests on other (older) Mac mini models have been successful, but both 2018 3.6 i3 Mac Minis running Mojave 10.14.6  are not consistently starting up once you supply power.

- Reset PRAM/NVRAM.
- `pmset -g` shows autorestart set to 1.
- The Mac WILL restart when I forcibly cut power to it.

What could be causing the inconsistent behaviour? More importantly, what's the solution?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. You can request migration.

Comment: Mac power management sucks. I spent days trying to keep a Mac from sleeping/hibernating when I was SSH'd into it. `pmset` is the pits. Eventually I had to disable everything that powered the machine down, and enable everything that powered the machine up.